# What is better let database throw an execption or throw custom execption

Tags: postgresql

I am developing an authentication system using express, So I have a unique email field in the database
should I check the email first and if it exists throw a new custom error Or let the database throw the error?

I want to know what is better

Comment: You do **both**. It a good approach to check for Business Rule violations in the app and the error is caught before it gets to the database. However **the database must always protect itself**. That way if your app is bypassed or another is later developed of  the same database but misses that rule your data is still protected. If for any reason you can only implement one of them then by all means put your protection as close to the data as possible. That is in the database in the database.

Answer (score 2):

Consumers of your API don't and shouldn't know what kind of database you use.

The error that makes it back to them should encapsulate all of it and specifically tell them what is wrong in some standard format with a good HTTP status code.

Database-specific errors leaking to the user should usually be considered a bug.

Comment: The problem is not sending the database error in the response because I will handle it and send a friendly response.  But the idea is good to practice letting the database throw the error then I handled it, or use a select query to check if the email already exists and then throw an error

Comment: That sounds more like something that shouldn't be an error in the first place (data integrity violations?). In the general sense, don't expose your underlying database in any form (it just provides more information in a targeted attack). In general, errors should occur when something that _shouldn't happen_ does, in fact, happen. If your DB shouldn't be in the state you're handling the error for, then keep the error and log it system-side.

Answer (score 1):

### Both.

You should write code to check that the email exists before you attempt the insert.

But if that check finds no email, you might still get an error, because of a race condition. For example, in the brief moment between checking for the email and then proceeding to insert the row, some other concurrent session may insert its own row using that email. So your insert will get a duplicate key error in that case, even though you had checked and found the email not present.

Then why bother checking? Because if you use a table with an `auto_increment` primary key, a failed insert generates and then discards an auto-increment value.

This might seem like a rare and insignificant amount of waste. Also, we don't care that auto-increment id's are consecutive.

But I did help fix an application for a customer where they had  a problem that new users were trying 1500 times to create unique accounts before succeeding. So they were "losing" thousands of auto-increment id's for every account. After a couple of months, they exhausted the range of the signed integer.

The fix I recommended was to first check that the email doesn't exist, to avoid attempting the insert if the email is found. But you still have to handle the race condition just in case.